# initialization order in python class hierarchies

Tags: python, initialization, super

In C++, given a class hierarchy, the most derived class's ctor calls its base class ctor which then initialized the base part of the object, before the derived part is instantiated. In Python I want to understand what's going on in a case where I have the requirement, that Derived subclasses a given class Base which takes a callable in its `__init__` method which it then later invokes. The callable features some parameters which I pass in Derived class's `__init__`, which is where I also define the callable function. My idea then was to pass the Derived class itself to its Base class after having defined the `__call__` operator

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        def _process(c, d):
            do_something with a and b

        self.__class__.__call__ = _process
        super(Derived, self).__init__(self)
```

1. Is this a pythonic way of dealing with this problem?
2. What is the exact order of initialization here? Does one needs to call super as a first instruction in the `__init__` method or is it ok to do it the way I did?
3. I am confused whether it is considered good practice to use super with or without arguments in python > 3.6

Comment: `def __call__(self, ...): ...` would definitely be preferable instead of `self.__class__.__call__`

Comment: yes, super without arguments these days

Comment: I cannot use the first syntax in your answer, since I need to construct the _process function within Derived classes __init__ method

Comment: you are currently not using the parameters a and b at all. are these supposed to be passed to the Base class init?

Comment: no, they are just used for computations within the process function, Base is then passing c and d to process. I corrected the code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the exact order of initialization here?

Well, very obviously the one you can see in your code - `Base.__init__()` is only called when you explicitely ask for it (with the `super()` call). If `Base` also has parents and everyone in the chain uses `super()` calls, the parents initializers will be invoked according to the [mro](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Basically, Python is a "runtime language" - except for the bytecode compilation phase, everything happens at runtime - so there's very few "black magic" going on (and much of it is actually documented and fully exposed for those who want to look under the hood or do some metaprogramming).

> Does one needs to call super as a first instruction in the **init** method or is it ok to do it the way I did?

You call the parent's method where you see fit for the concrete use case - you just have to beware of not using instance attributes (directly or - less obvious to spot - indirectly via a method call that depends on those attributes) before they are defined.

> I am confused whether it is considered good practice to use super with or without arguments in python > 3.6

If you don't need backward compatibily, use `super()` without params -  unless you  want to explicitely skip some class in the MRO, but then chances are there's something debatable with your design (but well - sometimes we can't afford to rewrite a whole code base just to avoid one very special corner case, so that's ok too as long as you understand what you're doing and why).

Now with your core question:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        def _process(c, d):
            do_something with a and b

        self.__class__.__call__ = _process
        super(Derived, self).__init__(self)
```

`self.__class__.__call__` is a class attribute and is shared by all instances of the class. This means that you either have to make sure you are only ever using one single instance of the class (which doesn't seem to be the goal here) or are ready to have totally random results, since each new instance will overwrite `self.__class__.__call__` with it's own version.

If what you want is to have each instance's `__call__` method to call it's own version of `process()`, then there's a much simpler solution - just make `_process` an instance attribute and call it from `__call__` :

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        def _process(c, d):
            do_something with a and b

        self._process = _process
        super(Derived, self).__init__(self)

   def __call__(self, c, d):
       return self._process(c, d)
```

Or even simpler:

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Derived, self).__init__(self)
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

   def __call__(self, c, d):
       do_something_with(self._a, self._b)
```

EDIT:

> Base requires a callable in ins init method.

This would be better if your example snippet was closer to your real use case.

> But when I call super().**init()** the call method of Derived should not have been instantiated yet or has it?

Now that's a good question... Actually, Python *methods* are not what you think they are. What you define in a `class` statement's body using the `def` statement are still plain functions, as you can see by yourself:

> > > class Foo:
> > >       ...    def bar(self): pass
> > >       ... 
> > >       Foo.bar

"Methods" are only instanciated when an attribute lookup resolves to a class attribute that happens to be a function:

> > > Foo().bar
> > >       main.Foo object at 0x7f3cef4de908>>
> > >       Foo().bar
> > >       main.Foo object at 0x7f3cef4de940>>

(if you wonder how this happens, it's [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html))

and they actually are just thin wrappers around a function, instance and class (or function and class for classmethods), which delegate the call to the underlying function, injecting the instance (or class) as first argument. In CS terms, a Python method is the partial application of a function to an instance (or class).

Now as I mentionned upper, Python is a runtime language, and both `def` and `class` are executable statements. So by the time you define your `Derived` class, the `class` statement creating the `Base` class object has already been executed (else `Base` wouldn't exist at all), with all the `class` statement block being executed first (to define the functions and other class attributes).

So "when you call `super().__init()__`",  the `__call__` *function* of `Base` HAS been instanciated (assuming it's defined in the `class` statement for `Base` of course, but that's by far the most common case).

Comment: thank you for your elaborate answer, this is exactly what I am wondering about. Base requires a callable in ins init method. But when I call super().__init()__ the __call__ method of Derived should not have been instantiated yet or has it?

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers out of curiosity: passing a callable child instance to the parent init strikes me as odd. would you see at that as a legitimate pattern? I don't know the wider context of the OT's problem, but in general calling a method in the parent class which is then overwritten by the children should do the job more cleanly... (?)

Comment: @mcsoini well, a callable is a callable, and Python doesn't care much about the concrete type. The nice point with passing callables instead of using inheritance is that it's much more flexible (cf the `strategy` pattern). So I see nothing wrong with this approach in and by itself - whether it's the best design for the task at hand is another question, but it depends on the context so there's no generic answer here.

Comment: thank you for your amazing help! This becomes technically fast, as I can see xD. I have to get rid of the C++/statically-typed way of thinking in order to understand this, I guess

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers thanks for the reply, appreciate it!

Comment: @CD86 well, yes, it's really a different world indeed. Not the most efficient system by far (in terms of raw processing perfs), but highly powerful and flexible when you undestand how it works. You just have to resist the tentation to do crazy things like dynamically changing the class of an object to implement the state pattern xD (been here, done that, very bad idea).